# List inside of List Comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

So, I start out with this code:

```
x = [1, [2, 3]]
y = [4, [5, 6]]
z = [7, [8, 9]]

amazing_list = [x, y, z]
```

and i do a simple list comprehension on it

```
print [l for l in amazing_list]
```

prints `[[1, [2, 3]], [4, [5, 6]], [7, [8, 9]]]` as expected

```
print [l for i, l in amazing_list]
```

prints `[[2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9]]` as expected

```
print [a for i, l in amazing_list for a in l]
```

prints `[2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]` as expected,

but then here's the kicker, here's where something isn't expected: what I'm trying to accomplish with the next line of code that I'm about to present is I'm just trying to print 2, 5, 8 (the first element of the list inside of the list):

```
print [a for i, l in amazing_list for a, b in l]
```

but this prints `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. Why?

I know that these accomplish what I want to accomplish:

```
print [l[0] for i, l in amazing_list]
print [a for a, b in [l for i, l in amazing_list]]
```

But what I want to find is why, conceptually, my first attempt at the comprehension didn't work.

Comment: Just unpack `l` : `[a for i, (a, b) in amazing_list]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a little carried away with the unpacking.

Note that the comprehension you're trying to understand

```
[a for i, l in amazing_list for a, b in l]
```

is logically equivalent to the following:

```
tmp = []
for i, l in amazing_list:
    for a, b in l:
        tmp.append(a)
```

with the result being in `tmp`.

Let's look at that innermost `for` loop.  When you get the error, `l` equals `[2, 3]`.

The interpreter is telling you that

```
for a, b in [2, 3]:
    print a
```

isn't going to work.  Why doesn't `a` equal 2 and `b` equal 3?  Well, what if you do this:

```
for x in [2, 3]:
    print x
```

What happens?  First time through, `x` equals 2.  Second time through, `x` equals 3.  Notice that in each iteration of the loop, you're just getting out one integer.  So if you replace `x` with `a, b` in the code, then the first time through the loop, the interpreter tries to do the following assignment:

```
a, b = 2
```

and that fails because 2 isn't iterable.

Comment: This was a pretty clear explanation. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

The `l` in that list comprehension is a single list, so iterating over it yields one and one value. And you can't unpack that into two values.

```
print [a for i, l in amazing_list for a,b in [l]]
```

If you put it into something that can be unpacked, it will work. `(l,)` would also work.

`[a for a,b in [1, 2]]` this is basically the same thing. And here it should be easy to see why it can't be done like that.